# Boost Variant with base class causes 'C1060 compiler is out of heap space'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm hoping someone here has a workaround for this. This code compiles fine on gcc, and VS2010 SP1 (Debug x32, Release x32, Debug x64), but fails for 64 bit Release builds with a fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space. I'm using Boost 1.52

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

typedef boost::make_recursive_variant<
    boost::blank,
    std::string,
    int,
    double,
    std::vector<std::vector<int> >,
    std::vector<std::vector<double> >,
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >,
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> >,
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<double> >,
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> >,
    std::map<std::string,boost::recursive_variant_>
>::type InfoHolder2;

class Test
{
    InfoHolder2 test;
};

class Test3
{};

class Test4
{};

template <class T>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(){};
    virtual std::string Foo(const T& val, const std::string& header = "")  const = 0;
    virtual T Bar(const std::string& buffer, size_t offset = 0) const = 0;
};

template <class Payload, class iArchive, class oArchive> 
class TestSer : Base<Payload>
{
public:
    TestSer():Base()
    {    }

    virtual std::string Foo(const Payload& holder,const std::string& header = "") const
    {
        return "";
    }

    virtual Payload Bar( const std::string& buffer, size_t offset = 0) const
    {   
        Payload retval;
        return retval;
    }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    new TestSer<Test, Test3, Test4>();
    return 0;
}
```

This fails every time. If I reduce the number of elements the variant can handle I can get it to compile, but that isn't really preferred as this works nicely for me. If I change the class to the version below, it works. Does anyone have any ideas for workarounds?

```
template <class Payload, class iArchive, class oArchive> 
class TestSer 
{
public:
    TestSer()
    {    }

    std::string Foo(const Payload& holder,const std::string& header = "") const
    {
        return "";
    }

    Payload Bar( const std::string& buffer, size_t offset = 0) const
    {   
        Payload retval;
        return retval;
    }

};
```

Comment: Try disabling MP ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx ) -> Project/Properties/Configuration Properties/C/C++/General/Multi-processor compilation . As you are using VS2010 this might do the trick, or use /ZM to increase the memory limit